# Is it allowed to store non serializable object in React context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is it allowed to store non serializable object in React context ?

I'm unable to find answer on this question in the [docs](http://Is%20it%20allowed%20to%20store%20non%20serializable%20object%20in%20React%20context%20?)

I know it is considered as a bad practice in redux store, see [here](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state).

Could you please provide any arguments or link to the docs about using non serializable objects in context?

Consider next example:

```js
class A {
 foo=()=> void 0
 bar=()=> void 0
}

const context = React.createContext(new A()) // is this ok ?
```

Comment: Are you able to use the context? And do the properties appear?

Comment: @evolutionxbox sure, I just curious if it is a good way

Comment: If the code works, then the answer is yes?

Comment: you can serialize it though. why do you think it is not serializable? because it does not contain own props? it is still valid object for context IMO. However as you pointed out, I do not think it is good practice. The documentation states that context is to share data that are considered global. If you have no global data to share then there is no point using context.

Comment: Good/bad practice is opinion though?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I agree, but I'd like to hear/see some arguments. For example here https://redux.js.org/faq/organizing-state#can-i-put-functions-promises-or-other-non-serializable-items-in-my-store-state  you can find some thoughts about using non serializable data in redux store. Is non serializable data works in redux store - yes? Is this ok - no.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I know this question might be downvoted and closed because of `opinion`. But I really like to hear more about it and I believe it is better to ask here than on twitter

Comment: @webduvet functions are not serializable, it is mean that you cant JSONify it

Comment: functions are not part of the object. you probably know they come from prototype. you can stil relialize your `new A()` object. react context is for sharing "gobal" data. so why would you want to share functions if they are not data?

Comment: @webduvet I can't answer on this question, there are a log of logic in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is perfectly fine to store non serializable object in React context. And here are some arguments.

First of all, I do not know (correct me if I'm wrong) any internal react mechanics that serializes or unserializes arbitrary context and / or assumes it to be serializable.

Second, react context now is a stable feature (in contrast like it was unstable some time ago). It is unlikely that something will change here, so we do not need to be proactively careful.

Finally, react context is just a way to pass something implicitly deep down into the components tree, not more, not less. React context is actually not about *storing* something, it is about *providing* and *consuming* something. You do not store things in context, you store it somewhere else, maybe in state, maybe somewhere, and then just provide it to consumers. So, why not to provide function to consumers if they need it? How it differs from passing things through props (where passing function is for sure not an antipattern)?

It is more about concrete scenario, and no one knows better then you, how and when to restrict particular context shape. For example, in our project we have some internal redux-like library that synchronizes stores between electron windows via rpc calls. It uses context and we specifically restricted (with typescript) context shape to be serializable (to be able to transfer it via rpc). On the other hand we have many cases where we pass non serializable stuff via context.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using class to solve this problem. The context worked fine. 
Sample code:

```js
class Stuff {
  data :any = {}
  getData() {
  return this.data
  }
  setData(_data) {
  this.data = _data
  }
}

const StuffInst = new Stuff();
// import this and use where you want
```

Please comment for suggestions/errors.